# Angular - $apply already in progress

Tags: angularjs

I have a general angular question:

I got the same error as here:
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/516.

Can this error ("$apply already in progress ") be a problem in my app? In my tests It seems that this error has no effects on my application. Every task inside still works.

Is it unproblematic to go with this error into the productive system?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Posting your code would be a start. First - it would not break the app, Production code should be clear of errors as it can be, it would tell others about your code quality:)

Comment: Could be a problem, we would need to know more. Try wrapping the code that is triggering that with `if(!$scope.$$phase) { ... }` and see if the error is still appearing

Comment: Its not really a problem in my code. The problem starts with boostrap-ui tooltip and a confirm window. Inside the tooltip function this error ocurs. @sal niro: But this code is inside the bootstrap-ui library. I don't like editing in this library. Maybe this change causes other errors?

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens when you try to run `$scope.$apply` and there is already one `$apply` in progress. A workaround that always prevents this error for me is to use `$timeout` instead of `$scope.$apply`.

Answer (score 1):

You stuck into this issue as your code try to trigger digest cycle before one got completed and that you are facing only in IE probably because of slow nature of IE. so my idea is to use  $scope.$evalAsync

```
$scope.$evalAsync(function () {
console.log('I am done.');            
});
```

OR

```
$scope.$evalAsync(angular.noop);
```

I hope this work for you.

Thanks